# Voltar para pagina anterior

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

```
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Single-Page-Transition-Effects-Using-jQuery-CSS3-page-js/
```

Eu quero fazer 1 site tipo este, uma pagina apenas mas divida em duas parte, direita e esquerda.
A estrutra do site vais se encontrar nestas duas divs sendo a primeira esta:

```
  <div class="page" data-jquery-page-name="11">
         <div class="title">Page 11</div>
              <div class="navigate" data-page-name="12" data-page-trans="slide-in-from-right">slide-in-from-right</div>
  </div>
```

e a segunda sera esta:

```
<div class="page" data-jquery-page-name="12">
                        <div class="title">Page 12</div>
                        <div class="navigate" data-page-name="11" data-page-trans="slide-in-from-left">slide-in-from-left</div>
                    </div>
```

a minha questão e como posso fazer para redireccionar para a segunda div, sendo que se eu fizer `header('Location:index.php');` automaticamente irei ser redireccionado para a primeira div (data-jquery-page-name="11") e o que eu realmente quero e que seja redireccionado para a segunda div (data-jquery-page-name="12)

Comment: Vc já tem a estrutura HTML/CSS/JS montada? A página que vc cita na pergunta é um plugin. Já baixou ele e tentou implementar?

Comment: sim, tenho todo o site montado já. O meu problema e quando envio 1 formulário que volta sempre para a primeira div. https://spil.development.pt

Comment: Seria o formulário de contato?

Comment: sim, pode testar, o link que enviei para entender melhor o problema!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao enviar o formulário, você está redirecionando para `index.php?sucesso=1`. Você pode usar o parâmetro `?sucesso=1` para abrir a segunda div diretamente em vez da primeira.

Como você está usando um plugin, ele só ativa a primeira div quando a página é carregada, então a única forma que vejo de ativar a segunda div é via JavaScript. Então você terá que colocar um script na index.php que irá ativar a segunda div quando a página for carregada e se o valor de `sucesso` for `1`.

Coloque no final do `body` o seguinte código:

```
<?php
if($_GET['sucesso'] == "1"){
?>
<script>
$(function(){

   $(".page.jquery-page-active")
   .toggleClass("jquery-page-active jquery-page-disabled");

   $("[data-jquery-page-name='12']")
   .toggleClass("jquery-page-disabled jquery-page-active");

});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: obrigado, ja esta funcionando mas mesmo assim ainda nao estou a conseguir ancorar para quando o formulário seja enviado, fica na segunda div e fixado no formulario de contactos por exemplo https://spil.development.pt/#contatos

Comment: Não entendi  o que quis dizer.

Comment: deixe ver se eu consigo explicar melhor, por exemplo, envio um formulário de contactos, e assim que o formulario seja enviado gostaria que ficas-se nesta parte da pagina https://imgur.com/a/k58oCXQ

Comment: Entendi agora, mas na pergunta vc diz que quer que fique na div `data-jquery-page-name='12'`!

Comment: ja consegui resolver, fiz o envio do formulario com ajax, e resolveu, pois assim nao necessita de atulizaçao de pagina para envio, mas voçe me ajudou bastante